# How to remove restrictions in latest IOS?

Tags: ios

This is probably a duplicate, but the &@$#& app won’t let me scroll through the suggestions.  I keep getting “page is restricted” in Safari for pages that are obviously quite innocent.  (Some of them confirmed so by checking on laptop.)

Multiple web pages say Settings: General: Restrictions, but there is no such path in IOS 12.1 and I have so far failed to find anything anywhere in settings.  Checked Privacy, Safari, and several other places.

One of those pages claimed to be telling us that it was for IOS 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things have changed with iOS 12 and the inclusion of Screen Time.

To access restrictions, follow these steps:

1. Go to Settings
2. Tap on Screen Time
3. Tap on Content and Privacy Restrictions
4. Enter the Screen Time passcode
5. Go to **Content Restrictions > Web Content** to access the restrictions related to web content

Comment: So the web page that said it was for IOS 13 was actually for IOS 11 or earlier.  It was indeed set to "no adult content" but none of the many pages it restricted were even in the same "country" as porn.  One of them was wedding dresses (trying to help my non-techie fiancée).